# Why isn't my tests working for this form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, testing, selenium, rspec, capybara

In Firefox, if I try to submit a post without a title, I get: **1 error prohibited this post from being saved**.

But when I run my test. It's a different story.

My Post model has `validates_presence_of :title`. My test looks like:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe 'Users' do

  it 'registered users should not be able to post without a title', :js => true do
    user = Factory(:user)
    visit new_post_path
    current_path.should eq(new_post_path)

    fill_in 'post[markdown_description]', :with => 'Bar'
    click_on 'Submit your post'

    page.should have_content('error')
  end

end
```

By the way, I am using Selenium (`:js => true`), because my submit button is actually an anchor link with some JS. Basically, when the link is clicked, JS triggers the form to be submitted.

Rspec returns:

```
Running: spec/requests/users_spec.rb
F

Failures:

  1) Users registered users should be able to post
     Failure/Error: page.should have_content('error')
       expected there to be content "error" in ""
     # ./spec/requests/users_spec.rb:13:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 7.9 seconds
1 example, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/requests/users_spec.rb:4 # Users registered users should be able to post
```

Answer (score 0):

The request may not make it to the controller action if you have `before_filters`. Check the log to make sure that the correct parameters are posting and that the action is not redirecting.

Another option is to include this in your spec:

```
click_on 'Submit your post'
save_and_open_page
```

which opens the current page in the browser so you can see what is actually being rendered.